# COBOL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cobol

Can anyone point me at a way to talk to SQL Server from Fujitsu COBOL?  Event talking to COM / ActiveX would be a start.

Many Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 1):

A few years back I used a product called Transoft U/SQL which allowed SQL Server to connect to MicroFocus COBOL data on Solaris UNIX machines, as if it where a linked server.

Not sure if this fits your scenario, but maybe worth a look.

Kev

Answer (score 1):

Here is some information that could get you started in another direction.  That is using ODBC to connect to SQL Server from COBOL.

http://www.easysoft.com/applications/micro-focus-cobol/server-express-openesql-odbc.html

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing practical about COBOL but..if you can use COM then maybe you could use ADO (msado15.dll)  or does COBOL have OLE DB or ODBC drivers of its own. If so, you could use them. But ADO is certainly worth looking at if COM works, as it has a huge number of methods & properties