# Getting a driver for VMS to connect to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, driver, cobol, vms

I want to connect from a COBOL/VMS system to an SQL Server 2005 instance. Could someone point me to a driver that works well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898055/cobol-to-sql-server) on SO.  Though not specific to VMS, many of the options presented there would work with VMS/ODBC.

You may also want to look at [FreeTDS](http://freetds.org/faq.html) (I've used it many times but never from VMS) if you are looking for an open source implementation you can customize.  Otherwise, the supported/commercial vendors that have products that would work include [Attunity](http://www.attunity.com), [DataDirect](http://www.datadirect.com), [EasySoft](http://www.easysoft.com/), and [CONNX](http://www.connx.com).

Comment: True - edited to reflect, though most presented options there would work on most/many VMS platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can have native connectivity to VMS files through Attunity Connect

Comment: The question assumes a multi-datasource environment (ie VMS is not the only source of truth) so the linkage was the other way around VMS -> SQL Server, not external to VMS.

Answer (score 0):

We currently do this from Pascal on VMS by calling a C procedure which in turns calls a Java class via JNI. The Java class uses JDBC to access the SQL Server database.  There is no reason a similar thing couldn't be done from COBOL.

If you didn't want to do the JNI stuff, you could write a socket server in Java which accepted messages sent from the COBOL program and then did the update across to the SQL server database.