# Acessing remote SQL server in VAX VMS

Tags: mysql, database, vms, vax

I have a SQL server on a remote machine and a VAX VMS based system is connected to the server machine.

Can someone please tell me how to access the SQL database on remote server from the VAX-VMS system?

Thank You

Comment: Try using your favorite search engine to look for something like `OpenVMS access MySQL` or `OpenVMS access SQL Server`. You'll find various things like [this](http://www.vmsmysql.org/doku.php).

Comment: Could you use ODBC ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998069/getting-a-driver-for-vms-to-connect-to-sql-server-2005/9272401#9272401